# Bias correcting penalized maximum likelihood / maximum a posteriori estimates

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias, regularization, bias-correction, map-estimation

Suppose an estimator $\hat\theta_T$ is defined as the value of $\theta$ maximizing:
$$\sum_{t=1}^T{l(y_t|\theta)}+\mu_T g(\theta),$$
where $l(y_t|\theta)$ is the log-likelihood of observation $t$, $\mu_T$ determines the strength of penalization (possibly a function of the sample size $T$), and $g(\theta)$ is a smooth penalty.

The Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) case corresponds to $\mu_T=1$ with $g$ the log-prior.

This is biased in finite samples in general (with bias potentially O(1)), and will be inconsistent if e.g. $\mu_T=O(T)$.

Are there techniques for bias correcting such an estimator, e.g. using information  about the derivatives of $g$?

Comment: Of course. But MLE bias is O(1/T). This bias is potentially O(1).

Comment: If $\mu_T=O(T)$ this is no longer Bayesian.

Comment: I said that the MAP case was when $\mu_T=1$.

Comment: Needs to be general to be useful I'm afraid.

Comment: Bias correcting ML is standard. It just needs 3rd derivatives of the likelihood. See Wikipedia. But I'm happy if your answer results in an estimator that is only as biased as ML, i.e. the resulting bias is O(1/T).

Comment: The bootstrap would do it, removing the first order term in the expansion of bias in terms of $T$ - but  I assume you are looking for something analytic?

Comment: Yes, I should have stated that, sorry. The bootstrap is not really feasible in context.

Comment: This question is very interesting. Could you please provide further search terms or wikipedia links for general reading?

Comment: @Ggjj11 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Second-order_efficiency_after_correction_for_bias to start with